# Can I limit a number passed into a method?

Tags: java, methods

I have a method that takes an integer as a value for size. The maximum size for this would be 14, otherwise it would overlap with other objects on the screen. Would it be possible for me to place a limit on the number so that it will give me an error if I try to pass in something larger than 14?

Comment: how about `if (value>14) throw new SomeException()`

Comment: yes, it would.  I suggest you try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common way to do this is check it in the method you are passing the variable in. If it does not match your requirement, throw an IllegalArgumentException.

```
 public void yourMethod(int size)
    {
       if(size > 14)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("max size is 14, size too big: " + size);

       // actual code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing inside your function, just check that the number isn'y outside the bounds. If it is, you can use the `throw` statement to throw an exception. You can define a custom Exception, or just use a built in one. Here's [more detail on throwing exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html), and here's [more detail on creating custom Exceptions.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-custom-exception-example/)